# Why can I no longer delete all iCloud data for my app at developer.icloud.com?

Tags: ios, icloud, nspersistentstore

iOS 8, Yosemite Beta and Mavericks
For months I have been routinely deleting iCloud Data from My app. Using:

```
[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
    removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:[_iCloudStore URL]
    options:options
    error:&error])
```

This no longer deletes the data in iCloud, as seen at developer.iCloud.com

When the method is about to execute I do:

```
(lldb) po [_iCloudStore URL]
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9C3184CA-0D89-4F0E-A085-9928A3895794/Documents/Stores/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/
mobile~932CEBB1-A974-4EA3-B0D4-9E31E3E318BE/MainStore/2B2A39E8-22DC-4238-AFA6-9BB78ECEF27C/store/iCloud.sqlite
```

and it has been several hours and the data will not disappear.

This is the view at developer.icloud.com

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oq9d6iel56m8n96/Screenshot%202014-09-23%2023.13.39iCloud.png?dl=0
```

What am I missing? Thanks.Mark